# PHP SESSION from a page to another

Tags: php, session, server

I've completed a website on my local server (MAMP) and everything was fine. The problem came when i uploaded it to a external server, i don't know why but i cant pass session variables from a page to another. I can make an echo in the same page in which i've created the sessions but if i do it in another page it shows nothing. I've checked the code several times even tought i don't think thats the problem, i just don't seem to make it work. Hope you can help me, thanks.

Here is some code:

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
session_start(); 
}  

$db_name ="discosco_discos"; //DAtabase name 
$db_username ="discosco_francis"; //database user name
$db_password ="****"; //database password
$db_path ="localhost"; // your database server name most of server use localhost

$db = @mysql_connect("$db_path","$db_username","$db_password");
@mysql_select_db("$db_name",$db);
?>
```

Comment: remove the condition just have `session_start(); ` at the top

Answer (score 0):

In order to use sessions, simply make an unconditional call to `session_start()` at the beginning of each page. Doing so will start a new session if one does not exist, or attach to an existing session if one does exist. It also performs all the magic to load `$_SESSION` from external storage.

If `session.auto_start` is enabled (not the default) then calling `session_start()` will raise an **E_NOTICE**; if you are *very* paranoid and *profoundly* offended by **E_NOTICE**s you can make the call to `session_start()` contingent on the return value of `session_id()`, but this is probably overkill for most purposes.

Comment: I think it is more server configuration related than php coding because localy it works fine.

Comment: Check your `phpinfo()` to see whether `session.auto_start` is enabled. That caught me up once with a "professionally-developed" php application I once tried to install.